# Renaming files with a previous date

Tags: powershell

I am running a program that creates 50 reports for different clients in pdf format on the first of every month.  I need the file name to reflect the previous month and current year in the file name i.e. 2014_09_ASI.pdf.  I am currently renaming the reports with the date after they are created using a batch file.  But I can only get a batch file to use the current month and not go back one month for the name.  Any idea if I can do this with PowerShell?

Comment: I'm not sure I could mark this of topic, but you may want to consider asking this on Stack Overflow, instead of on Super User (I would reword it a bit though, showing your existing batch script or something as "proof of effor")

Comment: `$LastMonth = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-5).ToString("yyyy - MM")` Will give you 2014 - 09 as a result which can be passed into the name of the file. If you are running the script on the 1st or 2nd of every month than you only have to subtract 3-5 days to get the previous month.

Answer (score 1):

Run the report and script at 11:59PM. This will allow you to rename the files with current year and month assuming the entire process can be run before the minute is up.

Here are some other [solutions](https://serverfault.com/questions/384718/how-to-create-a-yesterday-date-in-a-batch) on how perform what you want as PowerShell or Batch.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell's Get-Date cmdlets allows math and typecasting to string which you can use to your advantage easily.

To get last month:

```
(get-date).month - 1
```

To get a string of one month ago:

```
[string]((get-date).month - 1) + "_" + (get-date).Day
```

So to name to file in the format: Year_LastMonth#_ASI.pdf:

```
$LastMonth = (Get-Date).Month - 1
$year = (get-date).year

$newFileName = "$lastMonth $year ASI.pdf" -replace ' ', '_'
```

You could also use variable expansion to get the same done, or even as a one-liner if you really wanted, but depending on PS version I have found variable expansion to be a little unpredictable... So I used spaces to ensure accurate expansion and then replaced the " " in the new variable with "_".